# How to set screen resolutions in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

i developed an app it will fit 1024*768 screen .How to set the screens and controls for all resolution screens in windows 8.please tell me ..any samples on that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make pages for different screen sizes, they automatically scale depending on screen size. You should implement the snapped and filled mode though.

Comment: can you please elaborate the details.please let me know the possible links.

Comment: Try running your application in `Simulator` and try changing the screen sizes, than you'll get clear picture.

Comment: @user1727822 try [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx)